# Submit and removing from html don't work by using js

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my script. When I try to compile it IT don't give any error, but most of IT's functions don't work (like adding new article, removing it). Only removing value from search works. I would appreciate any help any help and guiding me how to fix this code mess

HTML Code :

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const todoList = document.querySelector("#todoList");
  const todoForm = document.querySelector("#todoForm");
  const todoSearch = document.querySelector("#todoSearch");
  const todoTextarea = todoForm.querySelector('textarea');

  //console.log("Dodaję zadanie do listy")

  todoSearch.addEventListener("input", () => {
    const val = todoSearch.value;
    const elems = todoList.querySelectorAll(".element");

    for (const el of elems) {
      const text = el.querySelector(".element_text").innerText;

      if (text.includes(val)) {
        el.style.setProperty("display", "");
      } else {
        el.style.setProperty("display", "none");
      }
    }
  });

  todoForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (todoTextarea.value !== "") {
      addTask(todoTextarea.value);
      todoTextarea.value = "";
    }
  });

  todoList.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("element_delete")) {
      e.target.closest(".element").remove();
    }
  });
});


function addTask(text) {
  const element = document.createElement("div");
  element.classList.add("element");

  //pobieram zawartość templatki
  const elementInner = document.querySelector("#elementTemplate").content.cloneNode(true);

  //wrzucam do elementu
  element.append(elementInner);

  //tworzę datę
  const date = new Date();
  const dateText = `${date.getDate()} - ${date.getMonth()+1} - ${date.getFullYear()} godz.: ${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}`;
  element.querySelector(".element_date").innerText = dateText;

  //wstawiam tekst
  element.querySelector(".element_text").innerText = text;

  //i wrzucam element do listy
  todoList.append(element);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, red 25%, orange 75%);
  min-height: 80vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cnt {
  max-width: 40rem;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

.formularz {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.form_row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form_label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

.form_message {
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 15rem;
  width: 93%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  resize: vertical;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.form_button {
  padding: .8rem, 1.6rem;
  background: #934915;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  transform: 0.6 all;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}

.form_button:hover {
  background: #bd5e1b;
}

.list_cnt {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.list_header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.list_search_form {
  width: 50%;
}

.list_search {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  ;
}

.list_title {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.element {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.element_bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.element_date {
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.element_delete {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: red;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element_text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="javascript" src="skrypt.js" defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cnt">
    <form class="formularz" id="todoForm">
      <div class="form_row">
        <label class="form_label" for="todoMessage">
                Podaj treść zadanie
            </label>
        <textarea class="form_message" name="todoMessage" id="todoMessage">

            </textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form_row">
        <button type="submit" class="form_button">Dodaj</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <section class="list_cnt">
      <header class="list_header">
        <h2 class="list_title">
          Lista Zadań
        </h2>
        <form class="list_search_form">
          <input type="search" id="todoSearch" class="list_search">
        </form>
      </header>

      <div class="list" id="todoList">

      </div>

      <div class="element">
        <div class="element_bar">
          <h3 class="element_date">03-12-2020 godz. 7:56</h3>
          <button class="element_delete" title="Usuń Zadanie"> Usuń </button>
        </div>
        <div class="element_text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio laudantium quasi blanditiis enim molestias explicabo id totam veniam corporis maiores.
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Template -->
      <template id="elementTemplate">
            <div class="element_bar">
                <h3 class="element_date"></h3>
                <button class="element_delete" title="Usuń task">
                    Usuń
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="element_text">
            </div>
        </template>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works when I try it.

Comment: None of the operations work on the initial list item because it's not inside `#todoList`

Comment: Can you precise what exactly place I need to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for all added items, but not the one that's in the original HTML, because your event listeners are on `#todoList`, and the original item is not inside that element. Move it inside to make that work.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const todoList = document.querySelector("#todoList");
  const todoForm = document.querySelector("#todoForm");
  const todoSearch = document.querySelector("#todoSearch");
  const todoTextarea = todoForm.querySelector('textarea');

  //console.log("Dodaję zadanie do listy")

  todoSearch.addEventListener("input", () => {
    const val = todoSearch.value;
    const elems = todoList.querySelectorAll(".element");

    for (const el of elems) {
      const text = el.querySelector(".element_text").innerText;

      if (text.includes(val)) {
        el.style.setProperty("display", "");
      } else {
        el.style.setProperty("display", "none");
      }
    }
  });

  todoForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (todoTextarea.value !== "") {
      addTask(todoTextarea.value);
      todoTextarea.value = "";
    }
  });

  todoList.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("element_delete")) {
      e.target.closest(".element").remove();
    }
  });
});


function addTask(text) {
  const element = document.createElement("div");
  element.classList.add("element");

  //pobieram zawartość templatki
  const elementInner = document.querySelector("#elementTemplate").content.cloneNode(true);

  //wrzucam do elementu
  element.append(elementInner);

  //tworzę datę
  const date = new Date();
  const dateText = `${date.getDate()} - ${date.getMonth()+1} - ${date.getFullYear()} godz.: ${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}`;
  element.querySelector(".element_date").innerText = dateText;

  //wstawiam tekst
  element.querySelector(".element_text").innerText = text;

  //i wrzucam element do listy
  todoList.append(element);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, red 25%, orange 75%);
  min-height: 80vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cnt {
  max-width: 40rem;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

.formularz {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.form_row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form_label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

.form_message {
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 15rem;
  width: 93%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  resize: vertical;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.form_button {
  padding: .8rem, 1.6rem;
  background: #934915;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  transform: 0.6 all;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}

.form_button:hover {
  background: #bd5e1b;
}

.list_cnt {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.list_header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.list_search_form {
  width: 50%;
}

.list_search {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  ;
}

.list_title {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.element {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.element_bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.element_date {
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.element_delete {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: red;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element_text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="javascript" src="skrypt.js" defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cnt">
    <form class="formularz" id="todoForm">
      <div class="form_row">
        <label class="form_label" for="todoMessage">
                Podaj treść zadanie
            </label>
        <textarea class="form_message" name="todoMessage" id="todoMessage">

            </textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form_row">
        <button type="submit" class="form_button">Dodaj</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <section class="list_cnt">
      <header class="list_header">
        <h2 class="list_title">
          Lista Zadań
        </h2>
        <form class="list_search_form">
          <input type="search" id="todoSearch" class="list_search">
        </form>
      </header>

      <div class="list" id="todoList">
        <div class="element">
          <div class="element_bar">
            <h3 class="element_date">03-12-2020 godz. 7:56</h3>
            <button class="element_delete" title="Usuń Zadanie"> Usuń </button>
          </div>
          <div class="element_text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio laudantium quasi blanditiis enim molestias explicabo id totam veniam corporis maiores.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- Template -->
      <template id="elementTemplate">
            <div class="element_bar">
                <h3 class="element_date"></h3>
                <button class="element_delete" title="Usuń task">
                    Usuń
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="element_text">
            </div>
        </template>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad you helped me Barmar! Have a great day